# Does MediaPipe Hand detection use an egocentric view (dataset)?

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, mediapipe

According to my knowledge, there are a variety of approaches for detecting hands based on different datasets.

(third-person view / egocentric view).

Does the mediapipe hand detector model use the **egocentric view** ?

If not, does Handtrack.js use it?

Do you know of a ML library running on a browser that does that?